# AS3 Project Mem Usage

Tags: actionscript-3

I Am Making A Cracker For AQW (Game)

But Sometimes It Crash
SO , I Got An Idea About Making ReOpen Function

But I Need To Detect The Mem Usage Of The Project
So if it's High , The Prog Restart It Self

Can You Help Me With That?

Comment: Could You Post Some Code And Specify Your Problem, So We Could See What's Going On?

Comment: What is "a cracker for AQW"?  What errors do you get when you say it crashes?  What do you mean by a "reopen" function? How do you know if the memory usage is high if you're unaware of how to detect it?  Please read:  http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 0):

AQW Cracker Is An Prog To Try User NAmes With Passes Until Two Match
It Crashes After I Open It (10 - 15 Min)
ReOpen Function Is A Function To Restart The Project
I Noticed That Before IT Crash It's CPU Usage Is Too High